# Can sendRedirect() act as a post method instead of get? - jsp/servlets

Tags: jsp, redirect, post, get

I have a simple form which accepts a username and a password. I have to use `sendRedirect()` method for the page to redirect to one page if log in is valid and to another if not. I need to use `sendRedirect()` and not `forward()` since the other pages are located in another server. I noticed that when using

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("FileName.jsp?paramName=" +value));
```

the `sendRedirect()` is using the `GET` method since name=value are being shown in the URL. This is not desirable for me since I don't want these values to show in the URL for safety reasons.

Is there a way to `POST` these values using sendRedirect() ? 
I tried to do a form with method `POST` which hides the values I need but still no luck

What can I do please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The only (dirty) workaround I see is to forward to an internal page containing a hidden form (with method POST) and a JavaScript script submitting this form.

Answer (score 12):

This is kinda old, but here I've succesfully run this:

```
response.setStatus(307); //this makes the redirection keep your requesting method as is.
response.addHeader("Location", "http://address.to/redirect");
```

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8 for explanation of HTTP 307 status code.

Comment: Very nice. Although the reference states `...the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user...`

Answer (score 2):

use javascript

```
$('#inset_form').html('<form action="FlowService" name="form" method="post" style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="idapp" value="' + idApp + '" /></form>');
        document.forms['form'].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a HTTP redirect will always use GET for the target page.

However, POST data are not much safer than GET data anyway. The user can still tamper with them. Store them in the session instead.

Comment: but if I store them in the session, will they still be showing in the URL? Sorry, I am very new to Web Technologies

Comment: The session won't help, since you want to redirect to another webapp on another server.

Comment: He could implement them in some shared way though. It's tricky unless both are on the same domain but it's possible.

Comment: * She :P What do you mean implement them in some shared way? @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0):

Check out this once :

```
String url = "http://www.mysite/servlets/theServlet";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I can't use forwarding since the other pages are located in another server!

Comment: As per my little knowledge its almost impossible ...sorry .

Answer (score 0):

Use sendredirect without giving any parameters, and hide those parameters in a session-scoped servlet, and if you need those parameters in the redirected page, use them through this servlet.