# URL redirection code in jsp is not working

Tags: html, jsp, timeout, response.redirect

From one jsp I want to get redirected to another jsp after a few seconds. I have the following code for that:

```
<body style="height: 302px; color: Olive">
    <h2> Result of your transaction </h2>
    <hr style="height: 5px; ">
    <p align="center">
    <h3> ${result}</h3>
    <br>
    <hr> 
    <form id="clientCall" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCClient/transactionResultMovieTheater.htm?">
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="${userId}"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.setTimeout("alert ('Now you will be redirected to the main Site');",3000);
        document.getElementById("clientCall").submit();
    </script>
</body>
```

But nothing is happening. It is just printing out ${result}, then staying in the same page. Have I written the wrong code? Please guide me here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`action` attribute of `form` tag is used when `input type` is `submit` or `button`.

In your case, input type is `hidden`, I think this creating the problem in your code. Try using another input type as `submit`.

Comment: The hidden input type is used to send back a value to the main site. I don't want the user to know this value.

Comment: Then another solution is as you are using jsp, why not redirect using jsp only at server side. Like when form submits post data then in jsp scriptlets, use methods like response.sendRedirect(url).

Comment: How should I code it? I need to send back userId to the client side as well.

Comment: when you use scriptlets to jsp code like <% ...your code ... %>, then code enclosed is excuted at the server side. So when say page1.jsp sends the post data to server then jsp code in the same is executed at the server side. So in the jsp scriptlet write the redirection logic also sends the post data came form page1.jsp to new redirected page. You need to look into how to send data from one page to another page in jsp.

Comment: If all the pages are located on the same server then you can use forward() method to do POST request. Refer it might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039121/can-sendredirect-act-as-a-post-method-instead-of-get-jsp-servlets

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.getElementById("clientCall").submit();` in the above code

I used

`window.open("http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCClient/transactionResultMovieTheater.htm?userId="+"${userId}", "_self");`

It worked perfectly fine!