# How can i redirect using method "POST" by DefaultRedirectStrategy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I wrote a custom `Failure Handler` in my Spring app

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        DefaultRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
        request.setAttribute("X-Http-Method-Override", "POST");
        response.setHeader("X-Http-Method-Override", "POST");

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login");
    }

}
```

What i'm trying to do is : in case of the failure login, i want to `redirect` to another page `/login` but with the `POST` method not `GET` method.

I tried to add `attribute` and `setHeader` but couldn't get what i want.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039121/can-sendredirect-act-as-a-post-method-instead-of-get-jsp-servlets

Answer (score 0):

No!!! you cant't have a post redirect without a hack. for reference you can have a look at
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect